# Binding parameters to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, parameters, parameter-passing

I have the code below to try to bind two different parameters to a stored procedure:

```
Dim ddlmanager As DropDownList = e.Row.FindControl("ddlManager")

            'ddlmanager.Items.Remove(ddlmanager.Items.FindByText(Name))
            Dim lblLevel As Label = e.Row.FindControl("lblLevel")
            Dim thisLevel = Convert.ToInt32(lblLevel.Text)
            Dim email As String = Profile.email

            Dim strConn As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RequestManagementConnectionString").ConnectionString
            Dim cn As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(strConn)
            Dim cmd As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("RM_Private.SelectLineManagerOptions", cn)

            cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Connection = cn
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@thisLevel", thisLevel)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email)

            cn.Open()

            Dim dr As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader

            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            ddlmanager.DataSource = dr
            ddlmanager.DataBind()

            cn.Close()
```

Now, when I debug this in Visual Studio, `@email` is set as a valid email address from `profile.email` and so is the other parameter, `@thisLevel`. It doesn't seem to be sending correctly to the stored procedure.

Can anyone help with this please?

Thanks.
DS

Update: code above successfully calls stored procedure now.
Update: sp called successfully and ddl populated

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if this is your problem, but that SqlDataSource without any properties but the ID seems to be suspicious. You call DataBind on the ddlManager.

Comment: thanks - i've updated the code, but it's not even getting to the binding stage. stored procedure is failing to get the parameters :(

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: i'm trying to call a stored procedure, RM_Private.SelectLineManagerOptions, which accepts two parameters, thisLevel and email, which in turn returns a result set to populate a dropdown menu. Have I got it completely wrong? Thanks for looking.

Comment: Another try: `SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure` is not the same as `CommandType.StoredProcedure`. Try the last - It seems that you have `Option Strict Off`

Comment: thanks steve - this was helpful. i can now pass the data across to the storedprocedure, but nothing binding to the dropdown. it might be a separate problem. thanks for the help

Comment: Well, good. I have posted the answer, but now,with your current edit is meaningless. I suggest to leave the original post as it was initially (rollback) and post a new question for the binding problem.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Discussed on [Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283684/the-poster-fixes-its-own-question-code-with-the-answers-received)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` You need to pull the data back into something, like a SqlDataReader for example.  Set the DataSource of the DropDown to the be the reader.

Change the CommandType as advised already. Then...

```
 Dim dr As SqlDataReader

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
ddlmanager.DataSource = dr
```

And then `Bind`

I don't know VB.net very well so you may need to amend this slightly

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much for the databinding help :)

Answer (score 1):

This problem could be avoided if you set [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) in your project properties. The `SqlCommand.CommandType` expects values of type [SqlClient.Data.CommandType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx). With `Option Strict Off` you are free to set the `CommandType` of your SqlCommand to a another enum value like you do using `SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure`

But `SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure` has a value of (int)1 while the correct enum, `CommandType.StoredProcedure`, has a value of (int)4. Not the same thing.

Another victim of Option Strict Off